# Linux SED search replace multiple per line

Tags: php, regex, search, replace, sed

I need to replace a whole bunch of PHP super globals in a clients website with a PHP function I made to clean the superglobals from xss attacks.

Here is what the original code might look like:

```
echo $_REQUEST['HELLO1'] . ' AND ' . $_REQUEST['HELLO2'];
```

I need it to look like this:

```
echo MYCLASS::myfunction($_REQUEST['HELLO1']) . ' AND ' . MYCLASS::myfunction($_REQUEST['HELLO2']);
```

The main issue, I need to do a search/replace on over 100 files!  Yikes!

So my solution was this (in linux shell):

```
sudo sed -i 's/\$_REQUEST[.*\]/MYCLASS::myfunction(&)/g' *.php
```

This works great as-long-as only one instance of "$_REQUEST" occurs per line... However with multiple instances, it screws up and does this:

```
echo MYCLASS::myfunction($_REQUEST['HELLO1'] . ' AND ' . $_REQUEST['HELLO2']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sed command:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\$_REQUEST\[\([^]]*\)\]/MYCLASS::myfunction(\1)/g' *.php
```

or in perl:

```
perl -pe 's/\$_REQUEST\[([^]]*)\]/MYCLASS::myfunction(\1)/g' file.php
```

Comment: You are welcome, I provided you a perl 1 liner as well in answer above to do same.

Comment: I have one issue though..  It replaces $_REQUEST[' '] WITH $_REQUEST(' ')   any idea how to fix?

Comment: changed myfunction(\1) to myfunction([\1]).. that did it!  thanks!

Comment: If anyone else has the same issue, I actually changed it to this myfunction($_REQUEST[\1])

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `.*` is greedy and will find the longest possible match it can. To work around that use `[^]]*` instead so that you don't inadvertently grab up an extra set of square brackets.

```
sudo sed -i 's/\$_REQUEST\[[^]]*\]/MYCLASS::myfunction(&)/g' *.php
```

In other regex dialects you could also write `.*?` to make the wildcard non-greedy, but that doesn't appear to work in sed (at least not in my version, not even with `sed -r`).

Comment: Thank you for your help.  The .*? concept is interesting.  the answer doesn't work.  We are trying the .*?.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, the following script will work where you pass the script the name of the file you are interested in
lets say the script is t.pl and your file is file.php
to output back to file.php
**perl t.pl file.php > file.php**
to output to another file so you don't overwrite your original
**perl t.pl file.php > another_file.php**

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$FILE_NAME = $ARGV[0];

open (FILE_NAME) or die ("Could not open FILE_NAME information file: $FILE_NAME \n");
@file_contents = <FILE_NAME>;
close (FILE_NAME);


foreach $line (@file_contents) {
       chomp($line);
       $line =~ s/\$_REQUEST\[.*?\]/MYCLASS\:\:myfunction\($&\)/g;
       print $line." \n";
}
```

exit;

Comment: Not sure I should have gotten the solution marking because I didn't use sed but glad this Perl script works for you.

Answer (score 1):

`sed 's/\$_REQUEST\[[^]]*\]/MYCLASS::myfunction(&)/g'`

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
sed -i "s/\$_REQUEST\[\([^\x5d]*\)\]/MYCLASS::myfunction(\1)/g" *.php
```

I had a lot of trouble matching `]`, so I've punted with `\x5d`.

Comment: I am getting an "-e expression #1, char 43: invalid reference \1 on `s; command's